# Database Design for a Configurable product with standard/customized configurations and Individually sold components

Tags: database-design

I have a problem designing database for a configurable product.
My application requirement is to create a configurable product from components which can also be sold separately

The products which can be sold alone have common attributes like size and color which can be combined while selling single

Also there is a Standard configuration and customized configuration which needs to be saved in database

Eg:- Bed being a configured product, it consist of *Base, Middle-Mattress, Top-Mattress, Legs, Headboard*...
All of this components except *Base* can be sold individually
There common attributes are size and color while *Middle-Mattress* has got a additional attribute as *Firmness*

The design that i came up with till now is ....
**Component_Master**
comp_id
comp_name
comp_desc
comp_type
sold_alone

**Component_Attribute_Header**
attrib_id
comp_id
attrib_name

**Component_Attribute_Details**
attrib_id
attrib_details_id
value

Now I am stuck at designing tables for standard configuration and customized configuration

Can anyone please help me with this design

Thanks in advance,
***Siddhesh Tawde***

Comment: What database will this be done on...
Is it a relational database?

Comment: This will be done on MS-SQL 2008 Express

Answer (score 2):

You may do this:

A product should have one or more parts. Each part should have one or more attributes. An assembly is a relation between parts and a product, once one part should be in different products, and one product should have one or more prarts. Customize the fields according to your specifications.

```
    tbl_product
    -----------
    prd_id:long PK
    prd_name:string
    prd_date:datetime

    tbl_parts
    ---------------
    comp_id:long PK
    comp_name:string
    comp_description:string
    comp_type:long
    comp_sold_alone:boolean
    comp_can_assembly:boolean

tbl_assemblies
--------------
    ass_id:long PK
    ass_description:string
    ass_date:datetime
    ass_product:long FK (tbl_products)
    ass_part_id:long FK (tbl_parts)

tbl_attributes
--------------
    atrb_id:long PK
    atrb_description:string
    atrb_part:long FK (tbl_parts)
```